# IIS URL Redirect with input parameters

Tags: redirect, iis-7.5

Having trouble implementing my first IIS redirect.

I have a URL:

```
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe/datasnap/rest
```

It can accept a range of input parameters separated by / characters:

```
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe/datasnap/rest/GetDateTime
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe/datasnap/rest/GetUsageData
```

etc, etc.

I'd like to redirect to a new module (a DLL in fact):

```
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrvISAPI.dll/datasnap/rest
```

I started by adding my redirect to the file itself (Q7WebSrv.exe) and it works fine by itself. It's only when I add variables that it starts behaving in ways I don't understand. For example if I have the redirect set to Q7WebSrvISAPI.dll$V$Q (using the EXACT flag) and request

```
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe
```

I get back

```
domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrvISAPI.dll/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe
```

No matter which $ variables I use, it's still trying to append part of the original URL to the redirect. I don't even want to get into what happens when appending the / input parameters.

Do I need to get into URL rewriting? That's a whole can of worms I'm not wanting to open just yet.

Comment: Read FRT to see what's wrong, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @FLDelphi could you share your URL rewrite rule? you could try this rule: `<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true"> <match url="(.*)" /> <conditions> <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domian.com" /> <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe/datasnap/rest/(.*)" /> </conditions> <action type="Redirect" url="http://ww.domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrvISAPI.dll/datasnap/rest/{C:1}" /> </rule>`

Comment: Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

you could try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true"> 
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.domian.com" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrv.exe/datasnap/rest/(.*)" /> 
  </conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="http://ww.domain.com/Q7WebServer/Q7WebSrvISAPI.dll/datasnap/rest/{C:1}" />
</rule>
```